# How to check for a specific value in an array of object and apply actions only to that object value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an array of objects. I'm trying to check for a specific value on an object in the array and show particular fields only for that object.

```
{
 "data" : {
  "items" : [ {
  "name" : "Basic Week",
  "id" : "WK2"
   },
  {
   "name" : "Basic month",
  "id" : "WK1"
  },
  {
  "name" : "Basic subscription",
  "id" : "11"
  },
  {
  "name" : "all time subscription",
  "id" : "11"
  }]
 }
}
```

Here I'm trying to check for a string that contains "subscription", so when I make a check, it should return me 2 objects:

```
{
  "name" : "Basic subscription",
  "id" : "11"
  },
  {
  "name" : "all time subscription",
  "id" : "11"
  }
```

Here is how I'm doing it:

```
    $.ajax("/api/1.0/getData",{
        success: function (data) {
          lists = data.filter(function (item) {
          if(item.name.indexOf("subscription")){
                    $("#some_div").show();
             }else{
                   $("#some_div").hide();}
          });
        }
    });
```

html:

```
<input type="text" id="some_div" style="display:none;"/>
```

But in the above case it shows the `div` for the all the objects, where as I would like to show the div only for the value that contains the string "subscription".

EDIT--------

```
$.ajax("/api/1.0/getData",{
        success: function (data) {
          lists = data.data.items.filter(function (item) {
          if(item.name.indexOf("subscription")> -1){
                    $("#some_div").show();
             }else{
                   $("#some_div").hide();}
          });
        }
    });
```

the above edited code still hides the id= "some_div" for all the objects.

Comment: Please add markup as well

Comment: item.name.indexOf("subscription") will not return if its in there or not, it will return a number, if not there, it will return -1, so you have to check for that.

Comment: As per most suggestions, i tried adding  if(item.name.indexOf("subscription") > -1) to my code and now it hides the div for all the objects, does not show at all

Comment: are you looking at the correct level of data here? foreach item in data, data will here only contain "items" ? try a console.log writeout for each iteration to see what item is set to

Comment: you're right @thsorens: its data.data.items.filter(function (item) {});

Comment: is some_div an id used for several divs here, or is it just a representation of some unique id for each one? an id should only be used ones pr page, since each iteration will flick all the divs with that given id, as @charlietfl mentions in his answer

Comment: now the question has completely changed making all the answers completely useless since they are responding to something completely different. Don't rewrite the whole context of a question. If it was incorrectly asked in the first place...start a new question

Comment: if you only want to show hide the target div, just use forEach, see update.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```js
var temp = {
 "data" : {
  "items" : [ {
  "name" : "Basic Week",
  "id" : "WK2"
   },
  {
   "name" : "Basic month",
  "id" : "WK1"
  },
  {
  "name" : "Basic subscription",
  "id" : "11"
  },
  {
  "name" : "all time subscription",
  "id" : "11"
  }]
 }
};

console.log($.grep(temp.data.items, function(element){
  return element.name.indexOf('subscription') > -1;
}));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score -3):

Since you are trying to search inside the items array, the data variable in the success callback is not the array you should filter.

Considering the structure of the object, you should access the array through: data.data.items.

So, try to put this in your success function:

```
success: function (data) {
      data.data.items.forEach( function (item) {
           if (item.nome.contains("subscription")) {
                $('#some_div').show();
           } else {
                $('#some_div').hide();
           }
      });   
}
```

--EDIT

You also need different id attributes for your HTML elements.

Like this:

```
<input type="text" id="some_div_0" style="display:none;"/>
<input type="text" id="some_div_1" style="display:none;"/>
<input type="text" id="some_div_2" style="display:none;"/>
<input type="text" id="some_div_3" style="display:none;"/>
```

And then you should use some attribute of your objects inside your array to show or hide each one.

Here, I am using the position of the object in the array to show or hide the correspondent HTML element:

```
success: function (data) {
      data.data.items.forEach( function (index, item) {
           if (item.nome.contains("subscription")) {
                $('#some_div_' + index).show();
           } else {
                $('#some_div_' + index).hide();
           }
      });   
}
```

Comment: same problem as most of the other answers... will only be set by last item in array

Comment: Yeah, each div need to have a different identifier, making it possible to hide or show each one based on this identifier.